# X64 Exception Type - 0D(#GP - General Protection)

Tags: linux, kernel, hang

Sometiems, I see this kind of error log:

https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=1641402

```
!!!! X64 Exception Type - 0D(#GP - General Protection)  CPU Apic ID - 00000000 !!!!
ExceptionData - 0000000000000000
RIP  - 00000000BFF8E976, CS  - 0000000000000038, RFLAGS - 0000000000210202
RAX  - 0000000000000001, RCX - 0000000000000010, RDX - AFAFAFAFAFAFAFA7
RBX  - 0000000000000020, RSP - 00000000BFF7EF60, RBP - 00000000BEC00F98
RSI  - AFAFAFAFAFAFAFAF, RDI - 00000000BFFA1720
R8   - 0000000000000000, R9  - 0000000000000028, R10 - 0000000000000020
R11  - 0000000000000002, R12 - 00000000BED0E618, R13 - 00000000BED0E818
R14  - 00000000BFF7F038, R15 - 00000000BED0E658
DS   - 0000000000000030, ES  - 0000000000000030, FS  - 0000000000000030
GS   - 0000000000000030, SS  - 0000000000000030
CR0  - 0000000080010033, CR2 - 0000000000000000, CR3 - 00000000BFC01000
CR4  - 0000000000000668, CR8 - 0000000000000000
DR0  - 0000000000000000, DR1 - 0000000000000000, DR2 - 0000000000000000
DR3  - 0000000000000000, DR6 - 00000000FFFF0FF0, DR7 - 0000000000000400
GDTR - 00000000BFBEE698 0000000000000047, LDTR - 0000000000000000
IDTR - 00000000BF1B2018 0000000000000FFF,   TR - 0000000000000000
```

This is a OS hang or Hardware hang problem?

Answer (score -1):

General Protection Fault
A General Protection Fault may occur for various reasons. The most common are:

Segment error (privilege, type, limit, read/write rights).
Executing a privileged instruction while CPL != 0.
Writing a 1 in a reserved register field or writing invalid value combinations (e.g. CR0 with PE=0 and PG=1).
Referencing or accessing a null-descriptor.
The saved instruction pointer points to the instruction which caused the exception.

Comment: If you have copied this from another source (https://wiki.osdev.org/Exceptions), please reference it properly.